# Как вывести в pandas самое последнее значение?

Tags: python, pandas

У нас есть таблица в pandas:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вывести самые последние значения из столбца "Buy"
я использовал данный код он выводит вместо последнего значения False показывает почему та  True

```
print(pd_data['Buy'].value_counts().index[-1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если просто хвост использовать для всего датафрейма, как раз и в нужном столбце последнее значение будет видно.
pd_data.tail(1)

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).